# What's meruach hak'ri and why do it?

Tags: halacha, agriculture

[In general, one is required to take *t'rumos* and *maasros* from grain only once the pile of grain is been smoothed (מירוח הכרי, *meruach hak'ri*).](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=7&hilchos=37&perek=3&halocha=1) (I think other *halachos* also kick in then.) What exactly is this act of smoothing, and why would a farmer do it?

Comment: What do you do when you finish raking leaves on your lawn? Do you square off the pile a little? Push it together a bit?